# Fail Installing Wifi driver for Realtek RTL8852BE (b852) on Ubuntu and PopOS

Tags: networking, kernel, wifi, drivers, realtek

I bought a new laptop Xiaomi Notebook Pro 14 2022 (Intel i7 12gen) (do I need a full specification?) and unfortunately I can't activate wi-fi. I've tried installing the latest Ubuntu and PopOS available images, but Wi-Fi doesn't seem to work on both out of the box (I chose pop OS). Right now, the only possible way to access the Internet on a laptop is with a modem from my smartphone.

**Listed below are some specifications:**

Network Controller Name (from hardware util): **Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852**

`uname -r` is `5.19.0-76051900-generic`

`lshw -C network` results:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2c:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:5e200000-5e2fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 14
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: enx0edb87e86af7
       serial: 0e:db:87:e8:6a:f7
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.19.0-76051900-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` results:

```
2c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Device [1d3e:c826]
```

`rfkill list` results:

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**I found different solutions, but here is what I tried:**

1. I tried installing the driver from the following github repo: https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be

**EFI Secure Boot disabled**

But this is what i get in return:

[console return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip5Lw.png)

```
...
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:249: /home/artkharlamov/rtl8852be/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1849: /home/ak/rtl8852be] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-76051900-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:637: modules] Error 2
```

2. I also found solutions to a similar problem in similar threads by installing the drivers from the following github repository: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89
   But that didn't help either.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to make my wi-fi work!

Answer (score 1):

The firmware of these series of network cards are not supported in some older versions of Linux kernel (like 5.10-5.12) but they're [said to be] supported in newer versions though they neither work by default nor work using the PPA firmware.

I had the same issue with RTL8822CE and (1) downgrading the kernel to 5.10 and (2) installing the firmware module from a PPA in GitHub solved the issue.

my suggestion is to downgrade your kernel and install from https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be again.

to downgrade the kernel open a terminal and write:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.10.0-13-amd64
```

this is for 5.10.0-13 version which worked for me, I hope this work for you as well!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and responsiveness! Your solution is definitely working, but unfortunately I can't use it because the processor on my laptop works much better only on the latest cores (Intel 12Gen). I tried installing the driver from the following repository https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw8852be and.. it worked! But to my regret, with some nuances. I understand the installed driver more and more, but periodically the connection is lost for a moment (the ping grows many times, but the packets are not lost). As soon as I collect more information, I will share it.